# Is there any way to create, assign and return variable inline?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to create a local variable in a function, calculate it and return that function in same line,

For Example making this function

```
 public static List<string> CalculateScore(this IEnumerable<GatheredMissionScore> list)
    {
        var calculatedScore = list.Select(gatheredScore => gatheredScore.ToString()).ToList();
        return calculatedScore;
    }
```

Like This

```
 public static List<string> CalculateScore(this IEnumerable<GatheredMissionScore> list)
        {
            return var calculatedScore = list.Select(gatheredScore => gatheredScore.ToString()).ToList();          
        }
```

Comment: What would be the use case for such operation if one to be added to the language? Some clarification of what you want to achieve/understand would help a lot in getting an answer.

Comment: you probably want `Sum` or `Aggregate` but you need to have a numerical score first and it's not clear from your example what your data structures look like.

Comment: I just wanted to make it expression body if this could be in line.

Comment: Just return the result of the expression and make it expression-bodied. Why do you want the variable?

Comment: Remove `var calculatedScore =`. Job done.

Comment: Yep thats work thanks :)  but is there any way to do it like I asked  in c#, or its reaaly meaningless to be make it inline ?

Comment: What's the point of the variable if you do that? Control leaves the method immediately due to the `return` statement. You can't use the variable. This is sounding like it might be an XY problem. If you want to inspect the return value while debugging, use the Autos window. It shows the last returned value.

Comment: `is there any way to do it like I asked in c#` Your first code sample is the way to do it if you want the temporary variable. My suggestion is the way to do it if you don't.

Comment: I couldn't see that at first look. Thank you all for clarification.

Comment: Using you use a variable opinion  based. You could also write it as [Expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) Use what you like, but use it consequent.